# Nested ID in JQuery selector

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to change the href of an a nested in a div called blink3:

```
$('#blink3 #backLink').attr('href',"#item5");
```

**Where the html code is as follows:**

```
<div style="float:left;text-align:center;" id="blink3">
<a href="#item4" class="panel" id="backLink">
<div class="divBack"></div></a>
</div>
```

works well in all browsers - **NOT IE 7** and I cannot figure out why, doesn't change the href.

Is this a IE 7 bug? JQuery? anything wrong with my code?

Any solutions?

Comment: How many `id="backLink"` do you have in your code?

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique to a page and if you have a number of the same IDs inline then I would imagine this is the root cause of your problems. Classes, on the other hand, are meant to be assigned to a number of different DOM elements.

Comment: Youre quick....I know I shouldn't have more than one... but I need it for some other things. would this cause the problem, and only in IE 7?

Comment: OK. So i need you experts to tell me : can I write $(this).attr('class')=="backlink"? as oppose to $(this).attr('id')?

Comment: @NinaNa: Probably yes. Duplicate `id`s *do* cause problems in IE7 where they usually don't cause problems in newer browsers.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Nick Craver (omg, where have you been around?) already stated it in a comment. It totally makes no sense to create a selector like `#id #id` because an ID has to be unique within your DOM by definition.

It looks like you break that rule and therefore, jQuery might select a wrong node.

You should replace your "backlink" `id`'s with `classes` and go for the selector like

```
$('#blink3 .backLink');
```

Comment: Out of curiosity. What if NinaNa has got multiple `<a/>`s within `id="blink3"` and he/she wants to access multiple ones of them? If `$('blink3')` is saved in a variable `blink3` first, wouldn't `blink3.find('#backLink')` be faster than `$('#backLink')`?

Answer (score 6):

I don't see any duplication of ID's in the question and I too had the same question even though all of my ID's are unique. A perfectly valid reason for wanting to do nested ID selectors is to retrieve an element if and only if it is a child of a specific parent. I've run into this with drag and drop UIs as well as tree nodes. While not a selector, this is what I've used in the past:

```
$("#parentId").find("#childId")
```

Answer (score 3):

IDs are supposed to be unique within a page. As Nick implies, you should have only one ID with the value of `backlink`. So a selector of `$('#backlink')` should be enough by itself. If you have more than one ID with the value `backlink`, then your HTML is wrong and you should fix that instead.

Answer (score 0):

To search nested elements using the `id` is as simple as concatenate **id selectors**, as for example:

`$('#selector_modal #modal-title')`

In this case we are searching a modal with id `selector_modal` and inside of it a *h4* element that has in this case the id `modal-title`.

Very simple.