# Change td value on dynamic div content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created dynamic table inside div.

```
<div id="data"></div>
```

Script to load data

```
<script>
 $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo base_url().'input_real/getDetReal';?>",
        cache:false,
        type:"POST",
        data:{id:id},
        success:function(msg){
         $("#data").html(msg);
        }
      });
```

Content HTML:

```
<table id="datatable2" class="table table-bordered" style="width: 100%">
    <thead >
     <tr>
     <th>#</th>
     <th>Code</th>
     <th>Name</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td id="dt1"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td id="dt2"></td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
```

How to change value of td with id=dt1
I try

```
$("#dt1").html("New data"); //not work
$("#dt1").text("New data"); //not work 
$("#data #dt1").html("New data"); // not work
```

Comment: Above code should have worked. When are you using above statements?

Comment: `$.ajax()` is asynchronous, are you calling your `html/text` function in a callback or anywhere where you're sure your table is already loaded?

Comment: Your table is getting loaded or not??

Comment: I'm sure table is loaded, mytable was shown on browser after i called $.ajax

Comment: Please add your complete script code then.

Comment: try like this:- `$('#data').find('#dt1').html("New data");`

Comment: Its Work. Thanks @Alive to Die

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said that:- `I have created dynamic table inside div`

So you need to do like below:-

`$('#data').find('#dt1').html("New data");`

i.e. - reference dynamically created element with it's imidiate static parent (find by traversing up-side).

Note:- Multiple same `id` for different elements are incorrect, when you are trying to use those `id` in jQuery. Use `class` instead of `id` for this purpose.

Comment: Why would he need to use that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665246/nested-id-in-jquery-selector

Comment: And I've just linked a question which explains why it's totally useless.

Comment: I have added note regarding that. Thanks for telling

Comment: Eh, I didn't think that there may be two or more tables in the page, OP didn't post his full code... Still, one should never do that, rather change the code to be valid.

Comment: @AlivetoDie Thanks, Yesterday i didnt found this answer here. Now, i was accepted your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your `$("#dt1").html("New data");` code into success function like that :

```
$.ajax({
   url:"<?php echo base_url().'input_real/getDetReal';?>",
   cache:false,
   type:"POST",
   data:{id:id},
   success:function(msg){
       $("#data").html(msg);
       $("#dt1").html("New data");
   }
});
```